# How can I move my vm IIS server to a new network

Tags: windows, iis, server, webserver

I have a VM running IIS server 3 websites. IIS determines which website to present based on the domain name. I want to move the VM to a DMZ network.

I have done this: The network has been created and has a gateway. A static IP has been assigned to the address of the server. The virtual adapter was configured with the appropriate VLAN ID and the server got the correct IP. The bindings of each website were adjusted to the new IP address. The server was removed from the domain in the process and I had to copy the websites from the network share they were initially at to a local directory at c:\inetpub\websites and I copied the permissions schemes of wwwroot.

I am unable to access the websites any longer. It has been a long time since they were set up and I don't remember how I managed to get the websites to present based on the domain name.

Please help! What do I need to do, or what did I do wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately IIS uses a more complex mechanism to determine which site to respond, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background. As you use specific networking setting like VLAN ID, you should use a tool like Wireshark to confirm the HTTP requests land on the server after the network change. Otherwise, you need to reconfigure the network to route the packets properly.

Comment: Okay. Thankfully I was able to get them back up by reverting everything back.

Comment: I will research more before just trying to jump ship and change everything.

Comment: Since IIS determines which website to display based on the domain name, you need to ensure that the DNS records for each domain name are properly configured to point to the server's new IP address. Also, you should ensure that any firewalls between the DMZ network and the public network are configured to allow traffic through the necessary ports for your websites.